# How to access EF objects using the TT templates

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the myModel.edmx with one table. I am used to work with the auto-generated entities.
Now I am trying the new TT option, but I can't understand where are the objects?

I want to execute a query, but cant find `object_name`

```
db.ExecuteQuery<object_name >
```

Answer (score 0):

TT files are not accessing EF objects, but reading the xmlfile(edmx), the is used to create the objects we'll use to get and set data to database.

TT Files on this case are used to generate automatically objects.

For your question you have to take a better look to the xmlformat of edmx file to help you understand, how objects are generated and how to call explicitelly that function